# PHP json_decode Parse Specific Object/Segments

Tags: php, json

I have a json file which i am reading the contents of from a url. I want to only parse a specific object/segment, store it separately and then display it.

```
.Json
    {
    "playerstats": {
        "id": "adwawdawdawdawd",
        "game": "123324234",
        "stats": [
            {
                "name": "tk",
                "value": 57656
            },
            {
                "name": "td",
                "value": 38439
            },
            {
                "name": "ttp",
                "value": 2659434
            },
            {
                "name": "tpb",
                "value": 847
            },
            ]
        "achievements": [
            {
                "name": "wbp",
                "achieved": 1
            },
            {
                "name": "bpl",
                "achieved": 1
            },
            {
                "name": "bdl",
                "achieved": 1
            },
            {
                "name": "kel",
                "achieved": 1
            }
]
}
}
```

So i want a seperate Array of "Stats" and a seperate Array for "Achievements".

Which then i can loop and get an output like this

```
Stats: name, value
       name, value
       name, value
       ...

Achievements: name, achieved
              name, achieved
              name, achieved
              ...
```

.

```
.PHP Attempt

   $url = "insertjsonUrlHere";
   $jsonFile = file_get_contents($url);
   $obj = json_decode($jsonFile, true);
   $stats = $obj->playerstats->stats;
   $achievements = $obj->playerstats->achievements;

   foreach ($stats as $key => $value) {
     echo $key."  ".$value."<br />";
   }
   foreach ($achievements as $key => $value) {
      echo $key."  ".$value."<br />";
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON is not properly formed. Test your JSON [Here](http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) (It displays the lines where the formatting is wrong).
If the JSON file is not properly formed, then `json_decode` will return `NULL`.

After correcting your JSON, this PHP code works as intended-

```
$url = "insertjsonUrlHere";
$jsonFile = file_get_contents($url);
$obj = json_decode($jsonFile, true);
$stats = $obj['playerstats']['stats'];
$achievements = $obj['playerstats']['achievements'];
foreach ($stats as $v) {
    echo $v['name']."  ".$v['value']."<br />";
}
foreach ($achievements as $v) {
    echo $v['name']."  ".$v['achieved']."<br />";
}
/*
    OUTPUT
*/
    tk 57656
    td 38439
    ttp 2659434
    tpb 847
    wbp 1
    bpl 1
    bdl 1
    kel 1
```

**EDIT:**

If you want to access the values of the `$stat` by name, this function should work-

```
function get_stats_value($stats, $name){
    foreach ($stats as $v) {
        if($v['name'] == $name){
            return $v['value'];
        }
    }
    return false;
}
$val = get_stats_value($stats, "tk");
var_dump($val);
//OUTPUT -> int 57656
```

Comment: Great answer, i have another quick one for you. If i wanted to get a specific stats->name e.g "tk" and return its value e.g "57656" so i can create getFunctions for each one how would i do this?

Answer (score 0):

You're using json_decode with the 'true' flag which means you get back an array and not an object. So in order to access your values change your code to the following:

```
$stats = $obj['playerstats']['stats'];
$achievements = $obj['playerstats']['achievements‘];
```

Answer (score 0):

See if this works. You could probably do a version with array_walk, too.

```
$stats = array();
foreach($obj->playerstats->stats as$a){
    $stats[$a['name']] = $a['value'];
}
$achievements = array();
foreach($obj->playerstats->achievements as $a){
    $achievements[$a['name']] = $a['achieved'];
}
```